# How to get values with same time with previous days same value

Tags: r

How to replace `NA`s in Var_1 with same previous days value

eg.row 4 has missing value - replace value/NA with the same time in the previous day(row 1).

similarly for row 7 with row 3, row 10 with row 9 and row13 with row 11. we can replace NA with previous value with `ZOO-na.lacf`

```
ID  Date                Var Var_1
1   21-01-2014 00:15    22  22
2   21-01-2014 00:30    33  33
3   21-01-2014 00:45    13  13
4   22-01-2014 00:15    NA  22
5   22-01-2014 00:30    22  22
6   22-01-2014 00:35    54  54
7   22-01-2014 00:45    NA  13
8   23-01-2014 00:15    23  23
9   25-01-2104 01:00    34  34
10  26-01-2104 01:00    NA  34
11  27-01-2104 02:00    2   2
12  27-01-2104 03:00    21  21
13  28-01-2104 02:00    NA  2
```

Comment: what if there's no previous day's value for that time? should we take the closes previoust day's value or leave it NA or something else?

Comment: Hi docendo , you are correct , we should leave as NA if previous days are not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `format` to get only time, and then split on that. Use `na.locf` to fill the NAs and `rbind` it back together, i.e.

```
library(zoo)

do.call(rbind, c(lapply(split(df, format(df$Date, format = '%H:%M')), function(i) {
                                     i$Var <- na.locf(i$Var); i
                                  }), make.row.names = FALSE))
```

which gives,

> ```
>  ID                Date Var Var_1
> 1   1 2014-01-21 00:15:00  22    22
> 2   4 2014-01-22 00:15:00  22    22
> 3   8 2014-01-23 00:15:00  23    23
> 4   2 2014-01-21 00:30:00  33    33
> 5   5 2014-01-22 00:30:00  22    22
> 6   6 2014-01-22 00:35:00  54    54
> 7   3 2014-01-21 00:45:00  13    13
> 8   7 2014-01-22 00:45:00  13    13
> 9   9 2104-01-25 01:00:00  34    34
> 10 10 2104-01-26 01:00:00  34    34
> 11 11 2104-01-27 02:00:00   2     2
> 12 13 2104-01-28 02:00:00   2     2
> 13 12 2104-01-27 03:00:00  21    21
> ```

You can then `order` on `ID` If you like as per usual`df[with(df, order(ID)),]`

Comment: Thank you very much sotos , Thats working... now how to take previous seven days average with same time?